# regular expression in javascript to capture a time string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match the time information from the following types of string:

```
<16>Jun 16 2013 12:40:39 abcdef
```

I am trying to use the following regular expression to extract the time information of `Jun 16 2013 12:40:39`.

```
var pattern = /\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]\b\s\d{2}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\d{2}\g;
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line shouldn't even compile:

```
var pattern = /\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]\b\s\d{2}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\d{2}\g;
```

First, the pattern should be `/pattern/g`, you don't have this structure well defined.

Reducing the regex:

1. `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]` is the same as `[a-z]{2,}` with the `(i)nsensitive-case` flag
2. You don't need to set a boundary `\b` if you will set a space `\s` right after
3. Optionally, as the string is well defined you can write just  instead of `\s`

You can end the line this way:

```
var pattern = /\b[a-z]{2,} \d{2} \d{4} (\d{2}:){2}\d{2}/gi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RegExp` `/([A-S])([a-u]+)(?=\s\d{2})(\s\d{2}\s\d{4})/g` to match uppdercase letters "A" through "S" , two lowercase letters if followed by space character and two digit characters, space character followed by two digits followed by four digits

```js
var str = "<16>Jun 16 2013 12:40:39 abcdef";
var pattern = /([A-S])([a-u]+)(?=\s\d{2})(\s\d{2}\s\d{4})/g;
console.log(str.match(pattern))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
/(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\s+(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01])\s+(\d{4})\s+([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)/gi
```

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/hS8lY5/1).

- Month: `(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)`
- Day: `(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01])` - 01 to 31
- Year: `(\d{4})` - 0000 to 9999
- Hour: `([01]\d|2[0-3])` - 00 to 23
- Minutes: `([0-5]\d)` - 00 to 59
- Seconds: `([0-5]\d)` - 00 to 59